# Why doesn't hSetBuffering return a new handle instead of changing the given handle?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, as we try to write most of our code in immutable way by not changing variables or passed parameters and instead we create a new value from the old one with required changes.

```
main = do   
withFile "something.txt" ReadMode (\handle -> do  
    hSetBuffering handle $ BlockBuffering (Just 2048)  
    contents <- hGetContents handle  
    putStr contents)
```

Then what is the reason than `hSetBuffering`, a function that takes a handle and sets its buffering mode, changes the passed `handle` itself instead of returning a new handle with required buffering mode?

Comment: For buffers that you only read from, that might be fine, but having two handles to the same writable object with separate buffers sounds like a recipe for madness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With regular Haskell values, there is no problem keeping older versions of a value around. However, `Handle`s are references to mutable resources allocated with the operating system, and carry state. After calling a version of `hSetBuffering`that returned a new `Handle`, what should happen to *earlier* versions of the `Handle` that are still kept around? Should they reflect the change? If the answer is yes, then the new-handle-returning version of `hSetBuffering` is a bit of a lie.

This new-handle-returning version of `hSetBuffering` could work if the type system somehow disallowed keeping old versions of the `Handle` after calling the function. It could do that by enforcing a constraint: functions that receive a `Handle` as parameter can only use that parameter *one single time*, and functions that "duplicate" handles like `dup :: Handle -> (Handle,Handle)` are *disallowed*.

There is a (not yet accepted) [proposal](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09756) to extend Haskell with the ability to enforce such restrictions. In fact, file operations are one of the motivating examples. From section 2.3 of the paper:

```
type File
openFile :: FilePath → IOL 1 File
readLine :: File ⊸ IOL 1 (File,Unrestricted ByteString)
closeFile :: File ⊸ IOL ω ()
```

Under this proposal, we can only have a single version of a `File` around at any given time. `closeFile` makes the reference to `File` unavailable so that we can't close an already closed file. Every read operation takes the previous version of the `File` and returns a new one along with the read data. And `hSetBuffering` would have a type like:

```
hSetBuffering :: BufferingMode -> File ⊸ IOL 1 File
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.